# How to get PunRPC methods in subclasses to work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Let's say I've got two classes: 'Ship' and 'ShipWeapon'.

```
IN SHIP:
 public void UseItem()
    {
components.gun.Shoot((JammerProjectile)collectableItemClass);
    }

IN WEAPON:
public void Shoot(JammerProjectile projectileClass)
    {
PhotonView photonView = PhotonView.Get(parentShip);
        PhotonView photonView2 = parentShip.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        PhotonView photonView3 = parentShip.GetPhotonView();
        photonView.RPC("Fire", RpcTarget.AllViaServer);
        photonView2.RPC("Fire", RpcTarget.AllViaServer);
        photonView3.RPC("Fire", RpcTarget.AllViaServer);
    }
```

This works, as long as the PunRPC method is in Ship. But, I want it in ShipWeapon. If I put it in ShipWeapon it seems to work, until called when I get a null error on argumentsTypes in PUN2 error handling.

```
[PunRPC]
    public void Fire()
    {
        Debug.Log("HI");
    }
```

Anyone know how come?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra PhotonView component seems to fix this, although not ideal.